# How to get 2 value from database using jquery autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, autocomplete

Sorry in advance if i'm unable to make it clear.

I have a table with 2 columns `item_description` and `item_price`, I have 2 `input` tags, one for *item name* and other for the *price*.

I'm using jQuery autocomplete to get `item_description` now what i want, if a user type *item name* and select one from autosuggest *price* `input` field should be auto filled with the selected *item name*.

Here is my php page:

```
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_description LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY item_description ASC");

while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row['item_description'];
    $data[] = $row['item_price'];
}

//return json data;
echo json_encode($data);
```

and here is the js:

```
$(".itemName").autocomplete({
    source: '../ajxphp/itemsname_autoSuggest.php',
});
```

Hope to get some help, thanx in advance.

Comment: @gerry thnx bro for editing my post

Comment: Calling someone a *bro* doesn't sound very professional and the other person might be slightly offended by it. Just a communication tip for next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope i understood what you mean,
you can always write your own autocomplete function

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var jsonAccArr = {};
    function Init() {
        var json =  [
                        { 'item_description': 'shlomi', 'item_price': 3 },
                        { 'item_description': 'yoni', 'item_price': 8 },
                        { 'item_description': 'david', 'item_price': 1 },
                        { 'item_description': 'roni', 'item_price': 5 },
                    ];

        json.forEach(function(element) {
            jsonAccArr[element['item_description']] = element['item_price'];
            $("#items").append("<option value='" + element['item_price'] + "'>" + element['item_description'] + "</option>");
        });
        var selectedName = $("#items option:selected").text();
        $("#price").html(jsonAccArr[selectedName]);
    }


    Init();
    $("#items").change(function() {
        var selectedName = $("#items option:selected").text();
        $("#price").html(jsonAccArr[selectedName]);
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="items">Product: </label>
    <select id="items">
    </select>

    <br>

    <label for="price">Price:</label>
    <span id="price"></span>
</div>
```

jsFiddle Link:
[Code Example](https://jsfiddle.net/c9hp3rh8/)